# git format-patch: Repository name in prefix or generated prefix

Tags: git

In a project with multiple repositories, I started to use `git format-patch HEAD^ --subject-prefix="PATCH some-repo-name"` to add the repo name to patches. With this with `git send-email` I get mails with a subject like `[PATCH some-repo-name 02/10] Add some function.` which makes it more clear where the patch should be applied.

Now I'm searching for a way to automatically add the repo name. I know that I can set the prefix with the `format.subjectPrefix` option (see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.22.1#Documentation/git-config.txt-formatsubjectPrefix)). I could do that on a per repository basis. But in my usual workflow I check out repositories more than once and sometimes remove working copies. With that it's not always easy to remember updating these settings.

So the question is: Is there some possibility to add a command / script to the `format.subjectPrefix` option or are there any predefined placeholders like %reponame% or similar?

I'm aware that "Repository Name" maybe isn't defined clearly. I would be happy with the name of the directory where I checked it out.

**EDIT:**

With the given answer I ended up with the following git alias:

```
git config --global alias.format-patch-repo '!git format-patch --subject-prefix="PATCH $(basename $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel))"'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git format-patch HEAD^ --subject-prefix="PATCH $(basename $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel))"
```

[`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---show-toplevel) shows the absolute path of the top-level directory of the working tree.

[`basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) outputs the name of the directory without leading paths.

[`$()`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) is a Command Substitution — the output of a command replaces the command name.

Comment: ...and logical continuation is to offer this as an alias for shell.

Comment: Thanks phd and 0andriy for the help. I somehow have only thought of some git solution and forgot that it might is simpler to just use a shell alias. So phd's answer and 0andriy's comment together are the solution I was searching for.

Comment: I used a git alias instead of a shell alias. That gives me a nice integrated feeling with a ```git  format-patch-repo``` command. I added the line in my original question as an edit.